# Migrate Hibernate 4.3 to 5.2 - missing table

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I'm trying to migrate from Hibernate 4.3 to 5.2.
The problem I end up having is with the following entity structure:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Post<T> {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "post_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag")})
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "x_post")
public class XPost extends Post<X> {
    // ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "y_post")
public class YPost extends Post<Y> {
    // ...
}
```

Before the migration this generated 4 different tables:
`x_post`, `y_post`, `x_post_tags`, `y_post_tags`

Now when I run the hibernate validation I get

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [post_tags]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)...

So Hibernate expects to have table `post_tags` now but I can't get why.

I suspect the problem is related to the naming strategy - previously I was using the `ImprovedNamingStrategy` but after the migration I had to add custom `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` that looks like that:

```
public class MyPhysicalNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl implements
        Serializable {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }

    protected static String addUnderscores(String name) {
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(name.replace('.', '_'));
        for (int i = 1; i < buf.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (
                    Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i - 1)) &&
                            Character.isUpperCase(buf.charAt(i)) &&
                            Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i + 1))
                    ) {
                buf.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return buf.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }
}
```

**Update [2018-01-25]**:

If I remove the `@JoinTable(name = "post_tags")` from the `tags` field the tables are generated as expected: `x_post`, `y_post`, `x_post_tags`, `y_post_tags`. If I leave it as it is in the example above it only generates the `post_tags` table.

So removing `@JoinTable` seem to fix the issue in that case, but if I want to have the join table name independent of the field `tags` (ex. if I want it to be singular - `*_post_tag`) I still need to use the `@JoinTable` which brings me back to the initial problem.

Comment: You tell the join table to be named "post_tags". Why would you expect the table name to be different then? Hibernate evaluates the name of the join table and passes that to your naming strategy.

Comment: I expect to have the same tables generated as they were before the migration to Hibernate 5. I haven't added the JoinTable annotation now. It's left over from before the migration.

Comment: This is precisely why reading migration documents are important.  For every minor and major release of Hibernate, there will often be new configuration parameters or strategy changes to support better, often more efficient ways of doing something.  In some cases you can set a config option to get the legacy behavior and in other cases you may have to supply a custom implementation as a part of the migration if you want your legacy application to continue to behave in the legacy way.

Comment: @Naros Yes, keeping the legacy behavior of my app is exactly what I want to achieve. I've read the migration page here https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc and I tried to fix my migration issues by setting the implicit strategy to "legacy-hbm" as suggested in the **Changed setting defaults** section but without success. If you have more concrete suggestion I would be happy to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA spec does not specify that 2 tables should be created in this case.

So, in my opinion, if you explicitly specify the table name, then why would Hibernate try to change that?

So, the Hibernate 5 behavior is more intuitive. Now, when you don't specify the `@JoinTable` and Hibernate generates two tables instead of one, you have two choices:

1. Either you remove the `@ManyToMany` from the `@MappedSuperclass` and declare it explicitly in entities X and Y.
2. You leave the `@ManyToMany` from the `@MappedSuperclass` and provide a custom `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` that tries to override the default `toPhysicalTableName` to take into consideration the values you provided in `@JoinTable`.